# Need o log data very fast using entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, frameworks, entity

I need to develop a software to monitor a value from a pressure transducer using a PLC and store the values in a datababe. The problem is i need to read de values every 20ms. Im using this code to save the data using entity framework and SQL. Im using a text box to see if the timer can handle the speed and confront with the SQL

Records made with the text box:
26/06/2017 - 10: 46:35.236
26/06/2017 - 10: 46:35.256
26/06/2017 - 10: 46:35.276
26/06/2017 - 10: 46:35.296

```
 private void mmTimer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    counter++;
    lblCounter.Text = counter.ToString();
    txtDT.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH: mm:ss.FFF\n"));

    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        storeDataBindingSource.DataSource = db.StoreDataList.ToList();
        StoreData objStoreData = storeDataBindingSource.Current as StoreData;
        {

            var _StoreData = new StoreData
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy - HH: mm:ss.FFF")
            };

            db.StoreDataList.Add(_StoreData);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

But when i look at the SQL Table the time values dont keep the same 20ms in every insert probably because of the huge amount of data that are beeing saved every time. Maybe i should use a buffer and insert all at once.

Any sugestion? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing you can do is instantiate your `DatabaseContext` outside of `mmTimer_Tick` so you don't eat the overhead each time you call it. Also, unless you're requirements include Entity Framework, you might be better off using raw ADO.NET or a micro-ORM like Dapper since EF has a lot of features you may not need and may not be the tool for the job.

Comment: Why do you have to make a DB call to read the data and another DB call to write it? I think you should write a stored procedure to do the operation at DB level. Your operation is very simple and can easily be done by DB engine. That will reduce a lot of overhead and increase the performance. you might even want to define this task a SQL job. Also, you might want to consider reviewing your indexes to speed up the read operation (although it can have a negative impact in the write operation)

Comment: what is the sql type of your sql column ?

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestion

use a buffer and insert all at once.

Definitely buffer readings.  As a further optimization you can bypass SaveChanges() (which performs row-by-row inserts) and use a TVP or SqlBulkCopy to insert batches into SQL Server.